# Node.js setTimeout context issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, settimeout

I'm trying to the following inside a module (Node 8.9.0LTS):

```
   const someResponse = await ajaxService.post('/data/search', params)
   const ms = 2000;

   const intervalID = setInterval(function(){
     if(Object.keys(personDataResponse).length === 0){
       let url = `/api?searchRequestId=1111`
       response = await ajaxService.get(url)
     }
   }, ms);

   setTimeout(function() {
      clearInterval(intervalID);
   }, ms * 5);
```

But I receive the following:

```
/path/to/project/project/api/router.js:27
            response = await ajaxService.get(url)
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:599:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/project/project/app.js:16:8)
```

Any suggestions?
The ajaxService.get() is accesible outside of the setTimeout.

Comment: What is the intent of the `setInterval` is here? It looks like you're running the request five times every two seconds and then stopping it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `await` inside a non-async function. So the simplest solution would be to change your function to `async`:

```
                               // v--- here
const intervalID = setInterval(async function () {
  if(Object.keys(personDataResponse).length === 0){
    let url = `/api?searchRequestId=1111`
    response = await ajaxService.get(url)
  }
}, ms);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use single quotes here?

`let url = '/api?searchRequestId=1111'`

You wouldn't need the back tick anyway if you are not concatenating any variable to your string.